# How to avoid sidekiq memory bloat when processing data in a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, sidekiq

I have a simple job, that loads a big json file and creates/updates records in the database. The job is performed via **sidekiq**.

Here is the simplified version of the job:

```
def call
    clients_data = HTTParty.get(@url).parsed_response

    create_or_update_clients(clients_data)
end

private

def create_or_update_clients(clients_data)
    clients_data.each do |client_item|
      begin
        process_remote_client(client_item)
      rescue => e
        Appsignal.add_exception(e)
      end
    end
end

def process_remote_client(client_item)
    client = Client.find_or_initialize_by(reference: client_item['ID']) do |new_client|
      new_client.company = @company
    end

    client.save!
end
```

Even though the data is processed in a loop, the memory increases with time. Then the sidekiq is restarted because the memory consumption oversteps the threshold value.

Is there any explanation why the memory is not being reused?

Comment: Is the issue sidekiq-specific? If you run the same code via a rake task / rails console, does the memory bloat still happen? I'm wondering whether it could be caused by something totally unrelated, e.g. a callback within `client.save!` ... or [maybe even by `Appsignal.add_exception(e)`](https://github.com/appsignal/appsignal-ruby/issues/57)?

Comment: Essentially, can you track this down to a **Minimal** reproduction example? You have many moving parts here; try taking each one out to find the true cause.

Comment: memory leaks are tough issues to track down. normally it's more economical (hello tech-debt :-/) to throw more hardware at the problem rather than spending expensive working hours to trying to track down the root cause

Comment: Thanks for the tips. @TomLord  it is caused by the save! call, which indeed has some callbacks. What I am wondering about is why independent calls to save! cause objects to be allocated but not released.

Comment: Well, what callback(s) are the culprit? Perhaps they're using a 3rd party library with a memory leak? And in the context of this code, do you actually need to run callbacks? - Perhaps you could massively optimise this rake task with a bulk SQL insert; bypassing all callbacks?

Comment: It is an option for sure, but the problem occurred when the input json has increased significantly. So removing callbacks is not an option at the moment, since it implies a lot of business logic refactoring. I just wanted to understand if it may be something sidekiq specific. As a next step I'll need to find out the culprit callback.